# How to exclude spe.js files from mix.js()

Tags: javascript, testing, laravel-mix

I currently have this:

```js
mix.js("./enterpath/**/*.js", "../../path/to/build/build.js");
```

We recently started to introduce tests in those folders for each js file `test.spec.js`

But now those files are also being compiled with the normal JS.

How do I tell mix to mix all `*.js` files except `*.spec.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not the best solution as it still compiles it, but at least I can choose not to include that file. This fixed my issue, but this shouldn't be the long-term solution:

```js
mix.js("./enterpath/**/*.js", "../../path/to/build/build.js").extract(["spec"]);
```